# How to evaluate function in parent environment without multiple assign calls?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang

I have R code like this:

```
f_parent <- function() {
 a1 <- 10
 a2 <- 20
 # .....
 a100 <- 100

 env <- environment()

 f_child <- function(a1, a2, ..., a100, env) {
  a1 <- a1 * 3
  a2 <- a2 * 5
  # .....
  a100 <- a100 * 1837

  assign('a1', a1, envir = env)
  assign('a2', a2, envir = env)
  # .....
  assign('a100', a100, envir = env)
 }
# .....
}
```

Is it possible to avoid multiple `assign` calls inside `f_child` function to evaluate `a..` variables in `f_parent` environment?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<<-` to assign into the parent environment:

```
f_parent <- function() {
 a1 <- 10
 a2 <- 20
 # .....
 a100 <- 100

 f_child <- function(a1, a2, ..., a100) {
  a1 <<- a1 * 3
  a2 <<- a2 * 5
  # .....
  a100 <<- a100 * 1837
 }
 f_child(a1, a2, a100 = a100)
 c(a1, a2, a100)
} 

f_parent()
#  30    100 183700
```

Take care that the assigned-to names are already defined in the enclosing environment. Otherwise,`<<-` will traverse parent environments until it finds something called `a1`, and failing that, will define `a1` in the global environment.

Comment: As I understand using <<- is not good practice for production code

Comment: My understanding is more that assigning to the parent environment in general — using `assign()` or `<<-` — is discouraged. Best practice would be to return and assign the results locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can put everything in a named list, and use `list2env`:

```r
f_parent <- function() {
    a1 <- 10
    a2 <- 20
    #....
    a100 <- 100

    f_child <- function(a1, a2, ..., a100) {
        a1 <- a1 * 3
        a2 <- a2 * 5
        #...
        a100 <- a100 * 1837
        setNames(list(a1, a2, a100), c("a1", "a2", "a100"))
    }
    
    ll <- f_child(a1, a2, a100 = a100)
    list2env(ll, environment())
    c(a1, a2, a100)
}
f_parent()
```

I agree with @zephryl's advice of avoiding the use of `assign` and `<<-`. Putting everything into a named list is usually better. Hopefully, this answer will nudge you into that approach.